# How can i create a navigation menu from a image for my website?

Tags: html, css, web

I wanted to create the nav bar using a image from Photoshop. I tried to used image as .png but i got nothing in my page. i.e, the page was blank. Here is the css of the page and image of the navigation bar . please someone help me.

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; } 

ul#awesome-menu {
    width: 517px; margin: 250px auto;
    list-style: none;
}


ul#awesome-menu li a {
    display: block; float: left; height: 56px;
    background-image: url(![enter image description here][1]/web/Project/butt.png) no-repeat; text-indent: -9999px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.ninja {
    width; 96px; background-position: 0 0;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.zombie {
    width; 108px; background-position: -96px 0;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.robot {
    width; 97px; background-position: -204px 0;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.assassin {
    width; 121px; background-position: -301px 0;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.jedi {
    width; 94px; background-position: -422px 0;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.ninja:hover {
    background-position: 0 -56px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.zombie:hover {
    background-position: -96px -56px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.robot:hover {
    background-position: -204px -56px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.assassin:hover {
    background-position: -301px -56px;
}

ul#awesome-menu li a.jedi:hover,ul#awesome-menu li a.jedi: focus {
    background-position: -422px -56;
}
ul#awesome-menu li a.jedi:hover {
    background-position: -422px -56px;
}

a { outline:none;}
```

Comment: ![enter image description here][1] is not a valid file path. Start there.

Comment: Can you double check the background property for `ul#awesome-menu li a`?  It looks like markdown butchered it somehow.

Comment: Please provide your url. As @Diodeus said `![enter image description here][1]` definitely is not a valid path. If that is what you actually have in your css file that is your issue. Another thing, typically the images folder is relatively close to your css file. For instance, if you have your css in a css folder and your images in an images folder in the same directory than your path would start out as `../`

Answer (score 0):

The `background-image` you have for the `ul#awesome-menu li a` selector is formatted in [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).  You'll need to format it correctly in CSS to get it to work.

```
background-image: url('../web/Project/butt.png') no-repeat;
```